# how to remove a path from LD_LIBRARY_PATH in tcsh?

Tags: linux, path, shared-libraries

on exiting/unloading a package, I must reset the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` back to its previous setting by removing a certain path from it. How to do that in tcsh or csh?

*edit1* to clarify.

Say the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is something like `path1:mypath:path2:path3:path4` and I do *not know* (in my script) anything about it except that it must contain `mypath`, [begin edit2 *which is stored in the variable `$MY_PATH`* end edit2] somewhere. Then I want to remove `mypath`, such that after the operation the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `path1:path2:path3:path4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bash user, but I'm pretty sure this will do the job for you.  It will most often leave a `::` in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that shouldn't cause any problems.

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | perl -pe "s[$DIR_TO_REMOVE][]g;"`
```

For bash users who might come upon this, use the following command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | perl -pe "s[$DIR_TO_REMOVE][]g;")
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: +1 that seems to work, though I'm not a perl person, so perhaps you can explain to me what the 's' and 'g' mean.

Comment: `s[][]` (normally written `s///`, but I used a different variant because / comes up in paths) is the regular expression substitution operator.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators  The `g` is a modifier meaning "do multiple replacements", discussed at the same link.  I figured there was a chance your path was in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` multiple times and you'd want to remove each instance.

Comment: How can I get this to work when I have the to be removed path in another env var? I tried `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | perl -pe 's[$MYPATH][]g;'`, but this doesn't work, presumably because of the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would have added this as a *comment* to robert's answer, but I do not have 50 reputation.  Yet.  (Hint: ***You*** can help fix that! ;-)

I'm a csh user (not by choice), so robert's answer is greatly appreciated.  But the regex used is susceptible to matching partial path elements, e.g., if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH = path1:mypath:path2:path3:path4`, then ...

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | perl -pe "s[/ath][]g;"`
```

... would yield `LD_LIBRARY_PATH = p1:my:p2:p3:p4`

Building on robert's answer, I've modified the regex to ensure matching only to a complete element in the path string, and put in multiple substitutions to handle the case of DIR_TO_REMOVE occurring at the beginning, middle, or end of the path.  I also added a substitutions to clean up leading colon (or path is only ":") and double colons ("::").  I couldn't figure out how to safely remove trailing colons since the csh parser is a pain about handling `$` as a meta-character for EOF (or end-of-string, in this case).  (*see* http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)

I've implemented this as a csh alias that accepts command-line arguments, since I wanted to make use of it with PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, et al.  The first parameter is the name of the path-variable to be modified.  The second parameter is the path-element to replace and the third parameter is the new path-element (or "" to simply remove the path-element matching the 2nd parameter).

I know Walter's question was how to *remove* a path, but since removing is really just replacing with a null value, This does still answer the question.  For my own use, I have different tool chains installed (e.g., GCC 4.1.2, GCC 4.8.1, ICPC 2013) and needed to easily swap-in/swap-out paths to the appropriate binaries, libraries and includes for the given tool chain, but keeping it transparent to the build management system.

Here's the code:

```
alias repath 'setenv \!:1 `echo $\!:1\: | perl -pe "s[^\!:2\:][\!:3\:]g; s[\:\!:2\:][\:\!:3\:]g; s[\:\:][\:]g; s[^\:][]g;"` '
```

Safely test it out in a csh terminal session as follows:

```
setenv myTestPath /myLDpath
setenv myTestPath2 /myLDpath/x86_64
setenv myTestPath3 /myLDpathDebug

setenv testPATH /SOME/PATH:/SOME/OTHER/PATH:${myTestPath}:${myTestPath2}:${myTestPath3}
echo "        Starting with the following path-variable content ..."
printenv testPATH
echo "        Remove $myTestPath from the middle ..."
repath testPATH $myTestPath ""
printenv testPATH
echo "        Put $myTestPath at the beginning ..."
setenv testPATH ${myTestPath}:/SOME/PATH:/SOME/OTHER/PATH:${myTestPath2}:${myTestPath3}
printenv testPATH
echo "        and remove it from the beginning ..."
repath testPATH $myTestPath ""
printenv testPATH
echo "        Put $myTestPath at the end ..."
setenv testPATH /SOME/PATH:/SOME/OTHER/PATH:${myTestPath3}:${myTestPath2}:${myTestPath}
printenv testPATH
echo "        and remove it from the end ..."
repath testPATH $myTestPath ""
printenv testPATH
echo "        Replace $myTestPath3 with /myLDpath/Debug ..."
repath testPATH $myTestPath3 "/myLDpath/Debug"
printenv testPATH
echo "        Done!"
```